# How to pass arguments to setter in javascript object?

Tags: jquery, oop, setter, getter

I have an object which is a list of filters corresponding to a select list. When the user selects from a drop-down I want update the object using this getter/setter. I'm also using an event listener. I thought the argument would be automatically passed into the handler.

```
var formFilters = {
  audience: 'All',
  get audienceFilter() {
    return this.audience;
  },
  set audienceFilter(input) {
    $('select').on('change', this.audienceFilter);
  }
};
```

Then to see what's going on:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
  console.log(formFilters.audience);
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is, or what you think the code above should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straigth forward actually:

```
formFilters.audienceFilter = 'customValue';
```

#### Update: https://jsfiddle.net/7431fz7u/1/

Comment: The thing I'm struggling with is how to pass the select element's value to the setter. `$('select').on('change', formFilters.audienceFilter)` doesn't appear to work